# Why is the implementation of ICorProfilerCallback::Initialize( IUnknown*) returning success and SETEVENTMASK failing (segmentation fault)?

Tags: .net-core, clang, cross-platform, windows-subsystem-for-linux, clr-profiling-api

Building a Simple Profiler for .NET in the Linux Platform. I am using the Platform Adaptive Layer provided by microsoft to have the header files of the profiling apis(corprof.h) and the dependent Macros and dependencies. Using MSBUILD in Visual studio and clang++ compiler with stdlibc++ library in a ubuntu WSL to compile the .so file. Here ICorProfilerInfo-> SetEventMask in the CLR is Failing.

This is my DLLMain.cpp - to load the .so into runtime

```
#include "Logger.h"
#include "OS.h"
#include "CoreProfilerFactory.h"
#include "CoreProfiler.h

extern "C" BOOL __stdcall DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstDll, DWORD reason, PVOID) {
    switch (reason) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        Logger::Info("Profiler DLL loaded into PID %d", OS::GetPid());
        break;

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        Logger::Info("Profiler DLL unloaded from PID %d", OS::GetPid());
        Logger::Shutdown();
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

class __declspec(uuid("805A308B-061C-47F3-9B30-F785C3186E81")) CoreProfiler;

extern "C" HRESULT __stdcall DllGetClassObject(REFCLSID rclsid, REFIID riid, void** ppv) {
    Logger::Debug(__FUNCTION__);

    const GUID CLSID_CorProfiler = { 0x805a308b,
                                    0x061c,
                                    0x47f3,
                                    {0x9b,0x30,0xf7,0x85,0xc3,0x18,0x6e,0x81} };

    if (rclsid == CLSID_CorProfiler) {
        static CoreProfilerFactory factory;
        Logger::Info("Returning CoreProfilerFactory to CLR!");
        return factory.QueryInterface(riid, ppv);
    }

    Logger::Error("GUID of Profiler not matching!");
    return CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE;
}

extern "C" HRESULT __stdcall DllCanUnloadNow() {
    Logger::Debug("DllCanUnloadNow() is invoked!");
    return S_OK;
}
```

Here is my CoreProfilerFactory.cpp inheriting from IClassFactory

```
#include "CoreProfilerFactory.h"
#include "Logger.h"
#include "CoreProfiler.h"
#include <new>


const IID IID_IUnknown = { 0x00000000,
                          0x0000,
                          0x0000,
                          {0xC0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x46} };


const IID IID_IClassFactory = {
    0x00000001,
    0x0000,
    0x0000,
    {0xC0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x46} };


HRESULT __stdcall CoreProfilerFactory::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppvObject) {

    if (ppvObject == nullptr) {
        Logger::Error("ppvObject pointer is null");
        return E_POINTER;
    }

    if (riid == IID_IUnknown ||riid == IID_IClassFactory){

        *ppvObject = static_cast<IClassFactory*>(this);
        this->AddRef();
        Logger::Info("Returning Instance of IClassFactory in the ppvObject pointer");
        return S_OK;
    }
    Logger::Error("GUID not matching!");
    return E_NOINTERFACE;
}

ULONG __stdcall CoreProfilerFactory::AddRef(void) {
    ULONG refcount = _refcount.fetch_add(1) + 1;
    return S_OK;
}

ULONG __stdcall CoreProfilerFactory::Release(void) {\
    ULONG refcount = _refcount.fetch_add(1) - 1;
    if (refcount == 0) {
        delete this;
    }
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT __stdcall CoreProfilerFactory::CreateInstance(IUnknown* pUnkOuter, REFIID riid, void** ppvObject) {
    auto profiler = new (std::nothrow) CoreProfiler;
    if (profiler == nullptr) {
        return E_OUTOFMEMORY;
    }

    auto hr = profiler->QueryInterface(riid, ppvObject);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        delete profiler;
    }

    return hr;
}
```

This is my CoreProfiler.cpp inheriting from ICorProfilerCallback3

_info is a CComptr<ICorProfilerInfo3>

```
CoreProfiler* CoreProfiler::_this = nullptr;

CoreProfiler::CoreProfiler() {

    _this = this;

}

CoreProfiler::~CoreProfiler() {

    _this = nullptr;
}

HRESULT __stdcall CoreProfiler::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppvObject) {
    
    if (ppvObject == nullptr) {
        return E_POINTER;
    }


    if (riid == __uuidof(IUnknown) ||
        riid == __uuidof(ICorProfilerCallback) ||
        riid == __uuidof(ICorProfilerCallback2) ||
        riid == __uuidof(ICorProfilerCallback3)){

        
        *ppvObject = this;
        this->AddRef();
        Logger::Debug("CorProfiler::QueryInterface");
        
        return S_OK;
    }

    return E_NOINTERFACE;
}

ULONG __stdcall CoreProfiler::AddRef(void) {
    return _refCount.fetch_add(1) + 1;
}

ULONG __stdcall CoreProfiler::Release(void) {
    auto count = _refCount.fetch_sub(1) -1;
    if (count == 0) {
        delete this;
    }

    return count;
}

const IID IID_ICorProfilerInfo3 = {0xb555ed4f,
                                    0x452a,
                                    0x4e54,
                                    {0x8b,0x39,0xb5,0x36,0x0b,0xad,0x32,0xa0} };

const IID IID_ICorProfilerInfo = { 0x28b5557d,
                                0x3f3f,
                                0x48b4,
                                {0x90,0xb2,0x5f,0x9e,0xea,0x2f,0x6c,0x48} };

HRESULT CoreProfiler::Initialize(IUnknown* pICorProfilerInfoUnk) {
    if (pICorProfilerInfoUnk == nullptr) {
            Logger::Error("pICorProfilerInfoUnk is a nullptr");
            return E_FAIL;
    }

    Logger::Debug(__FUNCTION__);
    HRESULT ok = pICorProfilerInfoUnk->QueryInterface(IID_ICorProfilerInfo3, (void**)&_info);

    if(!SUCCEEDED(ok)) {
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }
    std::cout << "Queried Interface";
    std::cout << "assert _info";
    assert(_info);
    

    _info->SetEventMask(
        COR_PRF_MONITOR_MODULE_LOADS |
        COR_PRF_MONITOR_ASSEMBLY_LOADS |
        COR_PRF_MONITOR_GC |
        COR_PRF_MONITOR_CLASS_LOADS |
        COR_PRF_MONITOR_THREADS |
        COR_PRF_MONITOR_EXCEPTIONS |
        COR_PRF_MONITOR_JIT_COMPILATION |
        COR_PRF_MONITOR_OBJECT_ALLOCATED |
        COR_PRF_ENABLE_OBJECT_ALLOCATED);
    std::cout << "SET EVENTMASK";
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT CoreProfiler::Shutdown() {
    Logger::Info("Profiler shutdown (PID=%d)", OS::GetPid());
    _info.Release();
    //delete _info;

    return S_OK;
}
```

"Queried Interface" is the last thing to be printed on the console before There is a segmentation fault(core dumped).
Why is This?

EDIT: Okay. So I found out that Accessing the functions in CComPtr<ICorProfilerInfo3>_info except that of _info->SetEventMask() and _info->ForeGC(), I get the Segmentation fault. Maybe _info returned in pICorProfilerInfoUnk->QueryInterface is not that of ICorProfilerInfo3? I'll have to find out.

EDIT2: Okay. the functions work with zeros or nullptrs as parameters. But, not with valid param values i.e moduleId or FunctionId etc. hmmm....